# How do I make a proper post request from Ionic app to an AWS lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have this for my post request code:

```
    var data = JSON.stringify({
      password: form.password,
      email: form.email,
      first_name: form.firstName,
      last_name: form.lastName,
      Cemail: form.emailConfirmation,
      Cpassword: form.passwordConfirmation,
      operation: "new_user"
    })

    var conf = {
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    }

    $http.get(this.signUpURL, data, conf)
      .then(function (res) {
        this.credentials = { username: form.email, password: form.password }
        callback(null)
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function (e) {
        callback(e)
      })
```

And then this as my lambda_function_handler:

```
from __future__ import print_function


def lambda_handler(event, context):
'''Provide an event that contains the following keys:

  - operation: one of the operations in the operations dict below
  - tableName: required for operations that interact with DynamoDB
  - payload: a parameter to pass to the operation being performed
'''
print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
```

This always prints null, am I sending the data wrong and accessing it wrong with the event parameter?

Answer (score 0):

In API Gateway you need to create a mapping template that maps the posted data to the Lambda function's parameters. You also need to make sure that template is applied to `GET` requests with a content type of `application/json`.

If you don't have the mapping template defined, or if you don't have it applied to `GET` requests, or you don't have it applied to requests of type `application/json` then you will get the behavior you describe.